# How do I decode UTF-8?

Tags: c++, utf-8, decode

I have a UTF-8-encoded string.
This string is first saved to a file and then sent via Apache to a process written in C++, which receives it using Curl.

How can I decode the string in the C++ process?

Comment: Decode to what? To unicode? Which platform?

Comment: What do you want to do with the string that makes you think you need a "decode" operation?

Comment: [One Possibility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html).

Comment: using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv

Comment: You need to specify for what.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams) that shows how to read utf8 .Alternatively http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/  has also manipulations to do it ( [C++ & Boost: encode/decode UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140223/c-boost-encode-decode-utf-8) ).