# C++ equivalent of PHP's utf8_decode function in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ & Boost: encode/decode UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140223/c-boost-encode-decode-utf-8)

I need to convert a `wstring` which has UTF-8-encoded text into it (incorrectly) into its own new corrected wstring.

PHP's `ut8_decode` function handles this perfectly. I can also do it through iconv:

from:

```
# cat wtf  | grep 1856 | awk '{print $2}'
å°ç³å·ãçç¾
```

to:

```
#cat wtf  | grep 1856 | awk '{print $2}'| iconv -f utf8 -t ISO-8859-1
小石川　玉美
```

In C# I was able to get this behavior with:

```
public static string Utf8Decode(string utf8me) {
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(utf8me));
}
```

Most of my searching has come up with Windows-specific workarounds. Since I am on Linux I assume I will want to use iconv but I am not sure how to do this in C++.

Comment: What type of `wstring`? UCS-2? UTF-32?

Comment: `utf8_decode` converts UTF-8 encoded text to ISO-8859-1 encoded text. ISO-8859 cannot encode the characters "小石川　玉美". You have a really strong case of screwed up encodings! [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

`iconv` is also a function `iconv()`

See GLIBC documentation:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Generic-Charset-Conversion.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html