# How do I convert between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 in C++?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, email-parsing

Does anyone know how to convert a string from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in C++?

I'm parsing an email to get email subject, which is encoded using [RFC-2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). I'm decoding a string to bytes using base64 decoding & Q decoding. But when I use byte stream as it is then garbage characters gets displayed in email.

Thank you.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140223/c-boost-encode-decode-utf-8

Comment: @mikedu95 If this question is already answered please flag/vote to close.

Comment: I leave the possibility that the answer, which is boost-based, isn't acceptable for the OP. Or should I flag/vote even in such case ?

Comment: thank you, I can't use boost in my application. I did tryouts with iconv, "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT /tmp/test1 > /tmp/test2; cat /tmp/test2" works for me.

Comment: I tried to implement same in c, iconv() api gives me error EINVAL, no getting exact reason.