# tiny-utf8: getting offset in characters / codepoints

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I am using [tiny-utf8](https://github.com/DuffsDevice/tiny-utf8), which works as a drop-in replacement for std::string, but with the ability to iterate over UTF-8 characters. Everything seems fine, however, sometimes my strings are inspected in their raw form (char*) by other libraries (in my case, it's RE2). The other libraries return offsets of substrings. Except, the offsets they return are for the raw string, which means, they are in bytes.

My question is, how do I convert these to codepoint / character offsets?

I found a method which seems to allow accomplishing exactly what I need in one call:

`utf8_string str = "My UTF-8 string";
str.get_num_resulting_codepoints(0, offsetInBytes);`

Except, it's protected. I can, of course, make it public but there has to be a reason why it was hidden; there should be another way.

I was also looking at utilising the `raw_get` method, but I am not sure if it's the right thing to do:

`str.raw_get(offsetInBytes) - str.begin()`

Comment: I would ask author of the library. It seems that original repository is [here](https://github.com/DuffsDevice/tinyutf8/). Moreover, it seems that in _master_ there is no longer `get_num_resulting_codepoints()` method.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks for the sleuthing! Probably a post on Stackoverflow will benefit the community as well, so I'll ask him here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `get_num_resulting_codepoints` was renamed in Version 2 to `get_num_codepoints` and additionally was made private.
I have drafted a new release [**"2.0.2"**](https://github.com/DuffsDevice/tinyutf8/releases/tag/v2.0.2), that makes `get_num_codepoints` public again (along with `get_num_bytes` and `get_num_bytes_from_start`).

You can use it the same way as you did before. However, the solution with subtracting iterators is a little bit more elegant as it does exactly the same and is equally efficient. I would stick to that one :)

Comment: Thank you, Jakob, both for the library and the reply!